# Specifying content-type in Meteor (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, http, meteor, content-type

How can I specify content-type in Meteor?

I've got a page that returns JSON but response header is `html/text` I need to make it `application/json`. I am using `iron-router` and then the json is displayed through a template. I just need to change the response header for that page.

How can I do it?

Comment: If you are using a server-side route, see my answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21565991/how-to-serve-a-file-using-iron-router-or-meteor-itself). Just change the headers to whatever you need.

Comment: ^ That's it. If you want to write an answer for this question so I can accept it, that would be great :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a simple example using a server-side route:

```js
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('jsonExample', {
    where: 'server',
    path: '/json',
    action: function() {
      var obj = {cat: 'meow', dog: 'woof'};
      var headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json'};
      this.response.writeHead(200, headers);
      this.response.end(JSON.stringify(obj));
    }
  });
});
```

If you add that to your app and go to `localhost:3000/json` you should see the correct result.